# How to use UIImpactFeedbackGenerator with objective c?

Tags: ios, ios10, vibration

Does any one know how to use UIImpactFeedbackGenerator with objective c in iOS? I cannot find any examples anywhere. I am using a framework that requires objective c, so it cannot be swift.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Good discussion here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator

Comment: I saw that unfortunately the engine/framework I am using is does not use swift :(

Comment: So translate it into Objective-C. I really don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *myGen = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle:(UIImpactFeedbackStyleMedium)];
[myGen impactOccurred];
myGen = NULL;
```

Comment: Note: iPhone 7/7+ or newer